# PHP: including 2 same php files in 1 page

Tags: php, php-include

i have a code

```
<div class="b4_content">
    <div class="col_left3 FloatLeft">
        <h3>Clients / Projects</h3>
        <div id="left_menu" class="left_menu">
          <?php
            require("admin/Connection/connection.php");
            require("admin/functions/functions.php");
            $toplvl=0;
            /* 1st include of linkCategory.php */
            include "admin/functions/linkCategory.php";
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_right3 FloatRight ">
        <div class="cright_padd">
          <?php
            $uploader="admin/";
            $catID = $_GET['catID'];                    
            if($catID==""){
                $toplvl=2;
                /* 2nd include of linkCategory.php */
                include "admin/functions/linkCategory.php";
            } else {
                $toplvl=0;
                include "admin/functions/viewImages.php";
            }
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ClearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see i have 2 includes (admin/functions/linkCategory.php) with same pages
My Problem is, the second include "admin/functions/linkCategory.php" does not show up.

Can you help me out

Comment: Why would you include the same page twice?

Comment: well i nid the same page. il just need to show level 1 and 2 of the category list. my indicator for that is $toplvl

Comment: Are you sure you are getting inside the conditional block to include it a second time?  Try putting an echo "in here" after $toplvl=2; to make sure you are definitely hitting the include

Comment: Are you sure $catID==""?

Comment: BTW: if i commented the first include. the second include shows up..

Comment: Could you post linkCategory.php code?

Comment: You don't have any functions, classes, or constants declared in `linkCategory.php`, do you? If you do... PHP will throw an error and cause your script to halt when it's included for the second time.

Comment: @Treby: also put an echo at top of 'linkCategory.php'. If it echoes twice, you know it's not the include that's failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `$toplvl` is a flag that's used within "admin/functions/linkCategory.php" to do different things. So, maybe the error isn't in this chunk, but in linkCategory.php itself.

Comment: Man your right.. nice guess.. i had a function in linkCategory.php, calling it twice will duplicate the created function. Thanks man. your thought helps.

Comment: That's the reason why I asked you to post linkCategory.php.  :-)   I gave +1 to Scott!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `$catID` is NOT equal to the empty string.

And btw, bolding doesn't work inside code blocks (if that's what you were trying to do).

Comment: It is an empty string. coz i tried echoing inside the condition

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, wrap whatever linkCategory.php outputs in a function. Include linkCategory.php once and replace the includes with a call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem still persists, you could set error reporting to show all and see if there's any output